# Laravel проблема с get

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Вид list.blade.php

```html
<!-- СПЕЦ ОДЕЖДА ОТЧЁТ -->



<?php
 use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
 use App\Models\Role;
 $root_url = Role::root_url();
  ?>





      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>


@extends('layout')

@section('title')

@stop

@section('content')




 <h2 class="main-header">Отчёт по спец одежде</h2>
<br>
  <div id="grid_table"></div>

<script>

  $('#grid_table').jsGrid({

  width: "100%",
  height: "600px",

  filtering: true,
  inserting:true,
  editing: true,
  sorting: true,
  paging: true,
  autoload: true,
  pageSize: 50,
  pageButtonCount: 20,
  deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete data?",

  controller: {
   loadData: function(filter){
   return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/spec_od",
    data: filter
   });
   },


  },

  fields: [
   {
    name: "firm",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
   name: "sotr",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
   name: "tovar",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
    name: "dat_pri",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
    name: "kol_ost",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
    name: "st_ost",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
    name: "sr_isp",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
    name: "dat_spis",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },
   {
    name: "kod_tov",
  type: "text",
  width: 150,
  validate: "required"
   },

   {
   type: "control"
   }
  ]

  });

</script>


@stop
```

Контроллер SpecController.php

```html
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Input;
use DB;
use PDO;

class SpecController extends Controller {

 public function __construct()
 {
  ;
 }

 public function getIndex()
 {
  
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);





     return view('spec_od/list') ;
 }

   public function getList()
   {
   $connect = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=CommonDB", "postgres", "postgres");
   //
   $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

   if($method == 'GET')
   {


    $data = array(
    ':firm'   => "%" . $_GET['firm'] . "%",
    ':sotr'   => "%" . $_GET['sotr'] . "%",
    ':tovar'     => "%" . $_GET['tovar'] . "%",
    ':dat_pri'    => "%" . $_GET['dat_pri'] . "%",
    ':kol_ost'     => "%" . $_GET['kol_ost'] . "%",
    ':st_ost'     => "%" . $_GET['st_ost'] . "%",
    ':sr_isp'     => "%" . $_GET['sr_isp'] . "%",
    ':dat_spis'     => "%" . $_GET['dat_spis'] . "%",
    ':kod_tov'     => "%" . $_GET['kod_tov'] . "%"
    );
    $query = "SELECT * FROM spec_odj WHERE firm LIKE :firm AND sotr LIKE :sotr AND tovar LIKE :tovar AND dat_pri LIKE :dat_pri AND kol_ost LIKE :kol_ost AND st_ost LIKE :st_ost AND sr_isp LIKE :sr_isp and dat_spis LIKE :dat_spis AND kod_tov like :kod_tov"; //sr_isp LIKE :sr_isp and dat_spis LIKE :dat_spis AND kod_tov like :kod_tov

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($data);
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
    $output[] = array(
     'firm'    => $row['firm'],
     'sotr'  => $row['sotr'],
     'tovar'   => $row['tovar'],
     'dat_pri'    => $row['dat_pri'],
     'kol_ost'   => $row['kol_ost'],
     'st_ost'   => $row['st_ost'],
     'sr_isp'   => $row['sr_isp'],
     'dat_spis'   => $row['dat_spis'],
     'kod_tov'   => $row['kod_tov']
    );
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($output);
    }
       return view('spec_od/list',$output) ;
   }
 public function postIndex()
  {



   return view('spec_od/list') ;
  }



}
```

И собственно роут routes.php

```html
Route::get('spec_od','SpecController@getList');
```

Лог ошибок:

```
[2020-01-17 08:47:14] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: firm' in D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\SpecController.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\SpecController.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', 'D:\\Bitnami\\wapp...', 38, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\SpecController->getList()
#2 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8230): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8297): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('getList', Array)
#4 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8276): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\SpecController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'getList')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8895): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8878): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8277): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8263): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\SpecController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'getList')
#11 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(7260): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'getList')
#12 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(7231): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(6897): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8895): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8878): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(6898): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#19 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(6887): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(6872): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(1901): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8895): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(17): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8887): App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(12022): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8887): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(10728): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8887): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(11728): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8887): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(11677): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8887): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(2440): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8887): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(8878): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(1879): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#39 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\storage\framework\compiled.php(1868): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 D:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.38-0\frameworks\laravel\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 {main}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103419/discussion-on-question-by---laravel---get).